# How can I use prepare for segue in a UITableViewCell class

Tags: swift, uitableview, segue

I want send data between UITableViewCell and UIViewController

I have a list of address, in my cell  I have a button (edit) and I want to send all the information about the address  in the cell

```
@IBOutlet weak var address: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var rfc: UILabel!
override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
}

override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

}
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.destination is ContainerVC{

        let vc = segue.destination as? ContainerVC
        vc.address = self.address.text
    }
}
```

Method does not override any method from its superclass

Comment: Don't do that. All *information about the address* is also available in the **model** and the segue must be performed in the **controller**

Answer (score 0):

Let's use segue inside your controller which contains the tableview which uses your UITableViewCell

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == segueIdentifier,
       let destination = segue.destination as? ContainerVC,
       let selectedIndex = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow?.row
    {
        destination.address = self.addresses[selectedIndex].text
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(destination, animated: true) // For example
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to do this from your `UIViewController` in which the `UITableViewCell` is implemented:

Assuming you have an array to populate your `UITableView`, the code would be something like:

```
import UIKit

class FirstViewController: UIViewController {

  @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
  var addresses = [String]()

  override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "showAddressDetail" {
            if let secondViewController = segue.destination as? SecondViewController {
                secondViewController.address = sender as! String
            }
        }
    }
}

extension FirstViewController: UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
         return self.addresses.count
   }

  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
         let cell: YourTableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "YourTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! YourTableViewCell
         cell.address = self.addresses[indexPath.row]
         cell.delegate = self
         return cell
   }
```

Since you have to call your function from an action triggered by a button on your `UITableViewCell`, you can implement a protocol on your cell:

```
import UIKit

protocol YourTableViewCellDelegate: class {

    func selectedAddress(address: String)
}

class YourTableViewCellDelegate: UITableViewCell {

    weak var delegate: YourTableViewCellDelegate?
    var address: String
}
```

And in your button action, call your delegate method like this:

```
@IBAction func selectAddress() {
    self.delegate?.selectedAddress(address: self.address)
}
```

This will trigger the delegate on your `UIViewController`. To handle the call, don't forget to assign your cell delegate to your view controller and implement your cell delegate in your controller:

```
extension FirstViewController: YourTableViewCellDelegate {

func selectedAddress(address: String) {
     // Do stuff with the selected address
    }
}
```

Comment: I need to do it when the user click the button instead the user select the row

Answer (score 0):

**To pass data from cell Class to Controller Class use delegate methods on edit action.**

- Define call back delegate method in UITableViewCell class:

  var callBack: ((NSDictionary) -> (Void))?
  Use DS as per your need.
- On Edit Action call delegate method and pass the data

  @IBAction func editAction(_ sender: Any) {
          callBack?(dictionary)
      }
- In cellForRowAt indexPath call delegate method with cell object

  cell.callBack = { (currentData : NSDictionary)
              in
              // Perform Action on data
          }

**To Pass Data from Controller class to cell class you can simply define a method in cell class and can call in cellForRowAt indexPath.**

- Define SetData(dictionary) in cell class
- In View Controller

  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
          let cell = tableViewOutlet.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CellName", for: indexPath) as! CellClassName
         cell.SetData(dict)
          return cell
      }